# Eclipse throws org.osgi.framework.BundleException on launch

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try launching Eclipse Indigo on Windows XP I am getting an error and the prompter tells me to go to the log file.

Apparently, it's throwing an `org.osgi.framework.BundleException`:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 0 2012-02-01 11:17:19.301 !MESSAGE
>   FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
>   Exception in org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.stop() of
>   bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide.    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:565)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1161)
>     at
>
> ...

Does anyone know how to fix this? I believe it stopped working because I played around with the Java path trying to get a project ported onto a Blackberry emulator.

However I tried setting the path to the correct value but I'm getting no luck.

I've even installed a fresh version of Eclipse into another directory but the problem does not go away.

Comment: I solved my problem! the answer was on the bottom of the page from the following link : 

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t92895.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t92895.html (as [indicated by Banana Man in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099358/cannot-launch-eclipse#comment11430285_9099358)):

> Put the unzipped "eclipse" folder under c drive. Create a shortcut of
>   "eclipse.exe". In the target, put this:
>
> C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.5.0_11\bin\javaw.exe"
>
> Note - "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_11\bin\javaw.exe" is where your
>   jre is installed at. You can change this path to match your your jre
>   path.
>
> In the start in, I have this:  C:\eclipse